# Get result from second function in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

write node js script and have next problem. How i get result from clientSession function

```
var User = function() {}
User.prototype.get_current_user = function (cookie) {
    var cookieManager = new co.cookie(cookie);
    var clientSession = new redis.createClient();

    var respons=clientSession.get("sessions/"+cookieManager.get("PHPSESSID"), function(error, result) {
        try {
            if(result != null){
                var session=JSON.parse(result);
                if(session.current_user_ID>=1) {
                    return session.current_user_ID;
                }
            } else {
                return "session does not exist";
            }
        } catch (error) {
            return "error : "+error;
        }
    });
    return respons;
}

module.exports = new User();
```

Function call

```
var User=require('user');
var user_data=User.get_current_user(ws.upgradeReq.headers["cookie"]);
console.log(user_data); // return null. Null it's wrong answer :)
```

Who has any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

From what I see `get_current_user` is an async function. So if you want to the `current_user_ID`, you will need to pass in a function to be used as a callback.

```
User.prototype.get_current_user = function (cookie, callback) {
    var cookieManager = new co.cookie(cookie);
    var clientSession = new redis.createClient();

    clientSession.get("sessions/"+cookieManager.get("PHPSESSID"), function(error, result) {
        try {
            if(result != null){
                var session=JSON.parse(result);
                if(session.current_user_ID>=1) {
                    callback(null, session.current_user_ID);
                }
            } else {
                callback("session does not exist");
            }
        } catch (error) {
            callback("error : "+error);
        }
    });
}
```

Then use it as

```
User.get_current_user(ws.upgradeReq.headers["cookie"], function(err, userId) {
  if(!err) {
    console.log(userId);
  }
});
```

Comment: Nice solution :) Thanks

Comment: @DmitriyKupriyanov if this answered ur question do set this as the answer.

Comment: It's recommended to replace callbacks with promises so it is easier to follow and debug the code.

Comment: recommendation it's cool, but sometimes we need breaking the rule :)